# puedo gestionar una base de datos de phpmyadmin con workbench?

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, phpmyadmin

tengo un dominio que tiene host junto phpmyadmin, aqui cree una base datos pero quiero saber si puedo gestionarla con workbench y que programas necesito para poder hacer la conexion. Gracias

Comment: Saludos "PGAdmin 3" es para base de datos "PostgreSQL" y PhpMyadmin es para "MySql" son dos cosas totalmente distintas es decir nose puede

Comment: Disculpame, me confundi de programa al hacer la pregunta, de casualidad sabes si puedo hacer eso pero con el workbench?

Comment: de hecho si al abrir Mysql-WorkBench tiene para modelar tu base de datos o consultar tus Tablas o Bases de datos

Comment: https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/database-connections/connect-database-remotely-mysql-workbench

Answer (score 0):

La verdad es que depende de tu proveedor de hosting. Si no permite conexiones externas, sólo podrás utilizar phpMyAdmin. En caso contrario, podrás conectarte a tu base de datos desde cualquier cliente de MySQL: Workbench, dBForge, Heidi, ...